# Allow anonymous controller to pass authentication .net core

Tags: authentication, .net-core, microservices, asp.net-apicontroller

I am provided with a microservice in .net core with Api controllers.
It has following code in Startup.cs to authenticate on every controller:

```
   services.AddTransient<IDIMContext, Context>(opt => {
            var acc = opt.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var mem = opt.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
            var conf = opt.GetService<IConfiguration>();
            var authenticate = new Context(acc, mem, conf);
            authenticate.Get();
            return authenticate ;
        });
```

ctx.Get() is the one which is authenticating, and I wanted to pass some controllers from this without authentication but I cannot really change ctx.Get() method.

Is there any possibility to exclude controllers from this code, so it will never trigger ctx.Get()?

Comment: what you show is just a service registration in DI container and container instantiate instances on demand only. If your controller doesn't use this service as a dependency, it will not be instantiated and `authenticate.Get()` will not be executed.

Comment: Well all the controllers are using IHttpContextAccessor so this get applied to all automatically. No other change is required.